# Wordpress custom plugin name not shown in roles and capabilities plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Plugin Used **User Role Editor**

I used plugin for assigning roles and capabilites for different users

But my custom plugin name is not seen in menu list(ex tablepress menu has different list under custom post type)

When i click on activate plugin in core capabilities/plugin option(In which users will get all the access to activate or deactivate)My plugin appears at left side of my dashboard.

How to get my plugin main menu and sub menus into that plugin.In which i can assign to roles individually.

Should i change anything with this code?

```
function custom_table_example_admin_menu()
{
  add_menu_page(__('Persons', 'custom_table_example'), __('Estuary Collaboration', 'custom_table_example'), 'activate_plugins', 'persons', 
  'custom_table_example_persons_page_handler');

  add_submenu_page('persons', __('Application', 'custom_table_example'), __('Application', 'custom_table_example'), 'activate_plugins', 'persons', 
  'custom_table_example_persons_page_handler');

// add new will be described in next part
  add_submenu_page('persons', __('Add new', 'custom_table_example'), __('Add new', 'custom_table_example'), 'activate_plugins', 'persons_form', 
  'custom_table_example_persons_form_page_handler');

//settings start
add_submenu_page('persons', __('Settings', 'custom_table_example'), __('Settings', 'custom_table_example'), 'activate_plugins', 'persons1_form', 
'custom_table_example_persons_form1_page1_handler1_setting');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_table_example_admin_menu');
```